# Using COM dll in a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, dll, qt4

In vs c++ I used the following code to use some functions in a dll file that I don't have its header

```
#import "dll path"
HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if (hr==S_OK)
    {cout<<"INITIALIZED\n";}

    Trans_ATLLib::ITransCriptPtr Trans;
    hr = Trans.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Trans_ATLLib::TransCript));
    if (hr==S_OK)
    {cout<<"INSTANCE CREATED\n";}

    hr =Trans->EnableLastCharTashkeel(true);
    if (hr==S_OK)
    {cout<<"EnableLastCharTashkeel DONE\n";}

    hr =Trans->EnableEmphaticLAM_RAA(true);
    if (hr==S_OK)
    {cout<<"EnableEmphaticLAM_RAA DONE\n";}

    VARIANT_BOOL test;
    test = Trans->SetText(arabic_string);
    if (test==0)
    {cout<<"error in setting the arabic sting\n";}

    string result;
    result = Trans->GetResult();

    istringstream iss(result);
    vector<string> phonemes;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),istream_iterator<string>(),back_inserter<vector<string> >(phonemes));
    return phonemes;
}
```

But I found that Qt doesn't use the same method.

Can any one help me in calling these functions in Qt?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use c++ - do the same! Qt is a set of libraries, not a different programming language - call to winApi everywhere you need, but don't forget that it is not portable.

Comment: thank you raiv i worked arround the problem by using the vs code as a exe file with some changes in it to avoid passing parameters